# Progress Dialog

Tags: android

-->I am new to Android And i want to show two progress dialog one after another??

-->First i want to show when my image is load from internet, when this process is done i have set A button on that Remote image.

-->When i click that button i want Dialog for second time..(on clicking button i have set video streaming code.. before video is start i want to close that Dialog..)

Any Help????
Thanks...

Comment: What have you done/tried so far?

Comment: i do not know how to handle it..

Comment: http://uploading.com/files/c657f58a/CatagoryVideoPlay.java/

Comment: you can download my code from Above link

Comment: Please update your code (put it in your question) and accept an answer (or comment those who aren't good enought)

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 threads. First for image when it is loaded then call another thread of video.
Make two runnable actions and two handlers to handle that

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "","Please Wait", true, false);

    Thread th = new Thread(setImage);
    th.start();

}

public Runnable setImage = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //your code 
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
};

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();
    }
};
```

Comment: ya. it is possible. For video you make one and for image one

Answer (score 0):

On Android it's best to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to execute tasks in the background while still updating UI:

1. Extend the AsyncTask
2. Start the progress dialog in onPreExecute()
3. Define the background task in doInBackground(Params...)
4. Define updating of the progress dialog in onProgressUpdate(Progress...)
5. Update dialog by calling publishProgress() from doInBackground()
6. Start a new Dialog #2 in onPostExecute().